# Разница между java.internal.org.xml... и org.xml

Tags: java, xml, intellij-idea, package, sax

`IDEA` предлагает импорт `java.internal.org.xml...` и `org.xml...` для всяких `SAX` парсеров и хелперов. В чём разница?

Comment: `...` в конце заголовка не добавляет

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего вы имели ввиду `jdk.internal.org.xml`, так как в пакете `java` нет `internal`.

Как пояснили [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/608336/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-rt-jar) пакеты не указанные в [javadoc's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/) не являются публичным интерфейсом и использовать их не стоит, так как в любом обновлении они могут измениться без предупреждения. То есть в вашем случае следует использовать классы из иерархии пакета `org.xml`