# Назначение пакетов rt.jar

Tags: java

Некоторое время назад был задан [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/607758/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-java-internal-org-xml-%D0%B8-org-xml) о разнице классов из пакетов `org.xml` и `jdk.internal.org.xml`(в вопросе указан `java.internal.org.xml`, что, вероятно, является ошибкой, так как в пакете `java` нет пакета `internal`).

Заинтересовавшись этим вопросом попытался отыскать информацию о назначении стандартных пакетов из `rt.jar` иии... не нашел! Достаточно легко найти подробное описание иерархии пакета `java` и `javax`, поверхностно про `org`, да и собственно все. В [спецификации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html) тоже этой информации не нашел, не исключаю что плохо искал. Подскажите где можно найти информацию о назначении этих пакетов? Почему часть классов из `org.xml.sax` дублируются в `jdk.internal.org.xml.sax`? Что вообще содержит пакет `jdk`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подобные пакеты являются особенностями внутренней реализации JDK. Разработчики не должны использовать их, так как они могут быть изменены без предупреждения.

Все пакеты являющиеся публичным интерфейсом описаны в javadoc.